# What is the most effective way to create a search filter for both single and compound terms?

Tags: java, search, design-patterns, enums

We have a situation where we are doing a search, and a user can provide a list of items as a filter for the search.

For example, let's say we were searching for recipes that had particular foods in them.  We might have a list of possible foods, like:

- beef
- chicken
- fish
- carrots
- peas
- onions
- rice
- beans

But we also want the user to be able to search for "any meat" or "any vegetable" and have it return anything that matches all the meat possibilities or all the vegetable possibilities.

We could just have the client do the parsing and when the user selects "meat", send all the meat choices.  But there is other logic we need to do when the user selects a higher category like that.  For example, if they select "any meat", we can search an additional database that has recipes that are flagged "meat", not by the individual meats.

(I'm making up this example, based on our actual business requirements which are far more boring, but this is essentially the idea.)

There are a couple of possible solutions I can think of, which are shades of the same thing:

- Have two different lists in the search criteria, one for an enum of
  individual items and one for an enum of groups, then combine the two
  when filtering searches.
- Have a single list in the search criteria with an enum that includes
  both individual items and group items.

But I feel like I'm missing a solution that might be a little more elegant in representing the group/individual relationship.  Is there a pattern that addresses this situation?

(PS: This is in Java, but I don't think that particularly matters.)

Comment: how about a `Map<Type, Set<Dish>>`, where `Type` is `meat` and `Set<Dish>` is `fish, carrots...`, getting the `Type` is `O(1)` and `Set::contains` is `O(1)` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maximum flexibility you can apply the [Composite design pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?CompositePattern). It allows you to treat a compound query (e.g., "any meat") just like any other query. In your case it would make sense to use an enum for the leaf.

First you need a parent interface type. In this case we can include a method that returns all the individual terms in a query.

```
public interface Query {    
    EnumSet<Term> getTerms();
}
```

Then for single terms use an enum that return itself as the "list" of terms:

```
public enum Term implements Query {
    BEEF, CHICKEN, FISH, CARROTS, PEAS, ONIONS, RICE, BEANS;

    @Override
    public EnumSet<Term> getTerms() {
        return EnumSet.of(this);
    }
}
```

For groups of terms you use the composite class:

```
public class CompositeQuery implements Query {

    private final List<Query> queries;

    public CompositeQuery( Query... queries ) {
        this.queries = Arrays.asList(queries);
    }

    @Override
    public EnumSet<Term> getTerms() {
        Set<Term> result = new HashSet<>();
        for( Query query : queries ) {
            result.addAll(query.getTerms());
        }
        return EnumSet.copyOf(result);
    }
}
```

And for the default groups you can define constants (I would declare these in the `Query` interface):

```
Query MEAT = new CompositeQuery(Term.BEEF, Term.CHICKEN);
Query VEGETABLES = new CompositeQuery(Term.CARROTS, Term.ONIONS, Term.PEAS);
```

The Composite even allows you to have groups of groups:

```
Query MEAT_VEGETABLES = new CompositeQuery( MEAT, VEGETABLES );
```

Comment: This makes sense.  I might even be able to make the Composite queries members of an enum or relate them somehow so JAXB can unmarshall both the leaves and the composites.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to searching anything, **Apache SOLR and Elastic Search** are the best. You can do all types grouping, categorization and other types searching in the mentioned framework. I will suggest to leverage Apache Solr or Elastic search instead of writing code from the scratch.

Comment: I am searching existing legacy databases on very specific fields.  I don't have the capability to import and index everything in the databases (existing or newly added).  Plus my code is already written, except for this new functionality.  I will look through the documentation to see how these tools might allow the criteria phrasing I'm looking for though.  Thanks.

Comment: @Risser, there is no need to index everything in database, Use Apache Solr. There is a facility in Solr to import from database tables and it can do index. After that you can search anything.